# Has anyone tried Service Discovery, with Hyperledger Composer "fabric-dev-servers"?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Using BYFN I was able to fetch the Anchor Peers using Discovery Services.

Now I am trying use the same for Hyperledger Composer "fabric-dev-servers" network but getting null.

Has anyone tried it and can provide the changes that might be needed?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: how do you fetch the anchor peers using discovery services?

Answer (score 0):

The fabric-dev-servers package is meant as a simple development fabric so that developers using composer can get up and running with a real fabric. 
If you need discovery then it would make sense to stick with BYFN as the fabric you want to develop against, or to look at the various hyperledger fabric resources and build a fabric to your requirements.